# Find indexof Object in ArrayList

Tags: vba, excel, arraylist, data-structures

I have a simple bit of test code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim testList As Object
    Set testList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    testList.Add Range("a1")
    Debug.Print testList.IndexOf(Range("a1"))
End Sub
```

Which returns an error rather than the index of the object in the list. Why is this, and if instead of adding a `Range`, I add a custom `myClass`, then what must `myClass` `Implement` to get this to work? Or is it not possible to lookup an object in an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Two `Range` pointing to the same cell are stored in two different objects. So either map the address/range in a dictionary/collection or add the full address to the list: `testList.Add Range("a1").Address(True, True, , true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim testList As Object
    Set testList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Range("A1") = "soready"
    Range("B1") = "tohelp"        

    testList.Add (Range("A1"))
    testList.Add (Range("B1"))

    Debug.Print testList.IndexOf("tohelp", 0)

End Sub
```

It prints `1`, which is the correct index of "tohelp".

Comment: Yes, this works for Ranges, but what about for other objects? I'm adding custom classes to the list. I believe this approach you've given works because `Range.Value` is the [default member](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx)... So would I have to set the default member of my class? Or am I misunderstanding how `IndexOf` works internally?

Comment: **So would I have to set the default member of my class** - I would say yes. This is how objects are used for sorting.